# What message should I display to a user who inputs an invalid username when trying to reset their password?

Tags: forgot-password, password-recovery

I'm building a new forgotten function on my site, in which users input their username or email and are then sent a link to reset their password.

If they input an email which is not registered to an account in my system I will not tell them in browser. The browser message will be the same as a successful reset ("A message with further instructions has been sent to that email address") and the email they are sent will say something like "this email is not registered on any account" with no reset link.

What do I do if they input a username which is not registered in my system? Seems like I have two options:

1. Display an error in the browser ("this username is not recognized")
2. Display the success message in the browser

The problem with #2 is they will be expecting an email that never comes, since I will have no email matched against the username (since the username doesn't exist). This seems like undesirable behaviour, but I'm also worried that #1 is bad for data protection reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were resetting the password with an email address (which is sensitive data), I would recommend saying something like

> If the email address you have entered is in our database, we will send a password recovery link to it.

However, you're using usernames to reset passwords, and usernames aren't sensitive data, so option 1 should be fine.

The only problem, though, is that you probably shouldn't be resetting passwords with usernames, as spammers can take this to their advantage. Assuming usernames are public on your website, a spammer could just send password recovery emails to everyone with an account on your website. So, I suggest you require the email address used to sign up for the account for password recovery.

Comment: Good comment about the username.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thanks

Comment: What do you mean about spammers? What do they gain by sending all my users password recovery emails?

Comment: @Sam - Maybe "trolls" is the better expression. There is rarely a forum without some trolls insulting other users, if they can spam their opponent with emails, they will happily do it.

Answer (score 0):

So #2 should be ruled out because it is actually incorrect information.

#1 is really the option. Go to gmail's or Microsoft's outlook login for example, and type in some impossible account name and both will tell you it doesn't recognize the email. Also, so what information are you giving away with #1? If an account with that username exists. You can get this information easily be trying to make an account with the target username.

I think you're fine with the #1 approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to show the message as you already did:

> A password reset link was sent to the email adress
>   "somebody@example.com".

Additionally I would offer help for the case that the user does not get the email:

> If you do not get the email in a few minutes, please check whether it
>   got into the spam folder and make sure it was the email address you
>   are registered with. For further help you can contact our [support](http://www.example.com/support).

With this message you not only conceal whether the email is registered (this can be important for certain sites), even more:

1. The user can see, what email address he tried, so he can check whether this is the correct one and try another one.
2. If the user does not remember the correct email address, he needs support anyway, so offer it right there with a link.
3. The message is worded positive, we do not imply that the user did a mistake or wants to misuse the system.

EDIT:
I overlooked that you are working with user names instead of emails. If they can be choosen freely **and** the user must enter the username instead of the email, I see no reason to keep the existence a secret. The username is even more difficult to remember than the email address though.